# Angular error if not loaded from head

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I try to load angular from the bottom of the body I always get the following error :

Failed to instantiate module xxApp due to: [$injector:nomod]

It works (almost, see bellow) perfectly when angular is loaded from the head, but angular website suggests it's better to load it from the body to be sure the DOM is fully ready.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="xxApp">
<head>
     <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <!-- another bunch of js files that need to be here -->
</head>
<body ng-controller="bodyController">
     <!-- My body -->
     <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
     <!-- another bunch of js files that are angular dependant -->
</body>
</html>
```

### JS

```
var xxApp = angular.module('xxApp', ['ngDb', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

xxApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});
xxApp.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
});

xxApp.controller('bodyController', ['$scope', 'om', '$location', '$document', '$filter', '$q', function($scope, om, $location, $document, $filter, $q) {
$scope.messageBoxVisibility = false;
//...
});
```

The thing is, I suspect that loading angular from the head is responsible for a random bug I get, which causes a specific part of my DOM, always the same, not to be processed by angular. This part is at the bottom of the body :

```
<div id="message-box" ng-show="messageBoxVisibility">
    <a ng-click="messageBoxVisibility = false"></a>
    <div>
        <b>//scopeVar//</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

scopeVar is set to false at the beginning of the controller so the message is not shown when page loads. But sometimes, let say 1/10 of the time, the message is shown, //scopVar// is visible as is and the ngClick is ineffective.

I'm using angular 1.4.7.

One more thing : when loading the page from a local server, I get 100% success, wether angular is loaded from the head or the body and I never see the message box.

Comment: Did you forget to include one of your dependencies or misspelled it? Because thats what the error is trying to say. It is pretty hard to tell what the exact source of error is.

Comment: Place the following code in body instead of the head: `<script src="js/angular.min.js" defer></script>` See if that makes a difference

Comment: Don't think I forgot a dependency otherwise it wouldn't work when angular is in the head either. With "defer" I ALWAYS have the error, wherever angular is included. Thank you both anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem solved.

The issue came from a minified lib that was loaded before angular. I just has to move it after and boom. I don't why it made angular all messed up, although I suspect it may come from an ajax request made the lib that always get 404.

I still don't understand why it didn't failed when loaded from the head because the order was the same though...

Answer (score 0):

I think that is impossible, 
for me the problem is that some of your files are not loaded correctly...
for example, someone of them return a non-200 result.

Try to open the dev-tools and ensure that all of javascript files return a 200 (http) status code.

Just a note, 
You need to load AngularJS before all scripts that depend on AngularJS...

---

1. angularJs
   1.1 angular components (3rd part libraries included)

If you are using jQuery with AngularJS could be a good thing include jQuery before AngularJS

Comment: I've already looked at the dev tools and no errors. However, you made me think that some files return 304 instead of 200, but I didn't care about that because it only means the file was not modified... Maybe that's the issue but it's weird.

Also, jQuery is included before Angular but thanks for pointing that out.